# Sending variables to OnTouch method

Tags: android, touch-event

In this method i set mode to 1;

```
bTouch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
  public void onClick(View v) {
    mode1=1;
      Intent startGame = new Intent(
        "com.example.mygame.GFXSurface");
        startActivity(startGame);
  }
});
```

when i call that mode in other class in onTouch method returns 0

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GameSurface gamesurface = new GameSurface(this);
    Mode mode2 = new Mode();
    mode= mode2.mode1; 
        if (mode == 1){        // this should be 1 but is 0
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
```

Anyone know the solution on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `mode1` values is not 1, It should be 0.

Just look at these two code lines..

```
Mode mode2 = new Mode();
mode= mode2.mode1;
```

Now  from 1 code line `Mode mode2 = new Mode();`

you are creating a new Class `Mode` object `mode2`.

As per the class object initializing rules you are allocated a memory for a new Mode class. So all its member variables and fields are initializing to with new mwmory.

Now come on code line 2

```
mode = mode2.mode1;
```

you are accessing `mode1` member field of newly created class `Mode` with object `mode2`.

So how it can hold the old value 1? (Think again)

```
Now how can you access this value in other class?
```

Either make a member field `mode1` as a **static** and directly access the field with class Name,

like,  `Mode.mode1`

Or use the same object for retrieving (get) value of mode1 from which you set the value for mode1.

Comment: so how do i get mode1 from Mode class?